# How can I replicate this MAXIFS formula in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, maxifs

new to the board and have a frustrating issue blocking me from proceeding with a project.  So I have a worksheet which documents times when warehouse pickers select items, and a formula that determines how long passed between picks, to monitor for excessive stops.  The formula looks like this:

```
=IF([@[PICK TIME]]-MAXIFS([PICK TIME],[Last Picked By User (Username)],[@[Last Picked By User (Username)]],[PICK TIME],"<"&[@[PICK TIME]])>1/12,0,[@[PICK TIME]]-MAXIFS([PICK TIME],[Last Picked By User (Username)],[@[Last Picked By User (Username)]],[PICK TIME],"<"&[@[PICK TIME]]))
```

[image: Here's a portion of the sheet it lives within (TIME FROM LAST is where the formula exists):]

Now, I have a 1.6 million record Access file that feeds into Power BI, and I need to replicate this functionality in DAX. I'd like to do it all at once, but in the end I'm fine with just a column that produces the time of the previous pick for that specific picker, and a measure can do the subtraction. [image: But here's what I end up with:]

How would I modify this code to prevent a circular dependency error and produce the desired result?  Thanks in advance for your help, and please let me know if you need anything else!

```
Prev Pick = 
VAR PT = 'Lucas Archive'[Date/Time]
VAR Pckr = 'Lucas Archive'[Picker]
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(MAX('Lucas Archive'[Date/Time]),
    'Lucas Archive'[Date/Time] < PT,
    'Lucas Archive'[Picker]=Pckr
)
```

Comment: how do you calculate a difference between the last yesterday time and the first today time?

Comment: We would need to add something to ignore if [Date/Time]-Prev Pick was over a certain threshold, like 4 hours or so; as you can see in the second screenshot, [Date/Time] includes both date and time thanks to the serial number.

Comment: I added the 3rd solution the the answer. Would be nice to have a feedback. As for me I'd prefer a measure for visual then calculated column, because you do not need to calculate all cases, but only a several selected cases and, I believe it's much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but takes a lot of time to calculate your 1mln rows. I'll think about a better solution.

Solution 1:

```
Prevpick = 
VAR currentTime=[Date/Time]
VAR tbl = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Lucas Archive'[Date/Time]),ALLEXCEPT('Lucas Archive',Lucas Archive[Picker],Lucas Archive[Pick Day]))
VAR tbl2 = Filter(tbl,[Date/Time]<currentTime)
RETURN maxx(tbl2,[Date/Time])
```

Solution 2 (much faster):

```
Rank = -- It's the first column
VAR currentTime=[Date/Time]
VAR RankDayPicker = 
         CALCULATE(
              RANKX('Lucas Archive','Lucas Archive'[Date/Time],{currentTime},ASC,Dense)
             ,ALLEXCEPT('Lucas Archive','Lucas Archive'[Picker],'Lucas Archive'[Pick Day])
         )
RETURN RankDayPicker

PrevPick = -- It's The second column
VAR currentRank = [Rank]
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
         SELECTEDVALUE('Lucas Archive'[Date/Time])
         ,ALLEXCEPT('Lucas Archive','Lucas Archive'[Picker],'Lucas Archive'[Pick Day])
         ,'Lucas Archive'[Rank]=currentRank-1)
```

Solution 3 : -- fast enough, but takes some time to calculate ~ 1 mln rows

```
Var currentTime=[Date/Time]
VAR timeValues=
    CALCULATETABLE(
       TOPN(
        1
        ,VALUES('Lucas Archive'[Date/Time])
        ,SWITCH(
            TRUE()
            ,[Date/Time]=currentTime,currentTime
            ,[Date/Time]<currentTime,currentTime-[Date/Time]
            ,100000
        )
        ,asc)
        ,ALLEXCEPT('Lucas Archive','Lucas Archive'[Picker],'Lucas Archive'[Pick Day])
    )

RETURN MAXX(timeValues,[Date/Time])
```

Comment: No dice, I'm afraid...still getting the circular dependency error. :(

Comment: But did you try?

Comment: Can you add the link to file?

Comment: Do you have other calculated columns in the table?

Comment: Hi Mik; no, no other calculated columns.

Comment: Yes, I tried your formula but got the error again.  As for a link to the file...can I link a 36MB file here?

Comment: You can add a link to a cloud.

Comment: You can add a table with some dummy data to the question body

Comment: I’ll check the syntax tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @AnalystMan, I altered the answer, but it takes long time to go through all the table. I'll think about a faster one.

Comment: I added a new solution, So you can check.

Comment: Sorry @Mik, was busy yesterday...your solution works!  Taking a little time to calculate is no big deal to get this functionality.  I really appreciate your assistance and time!

Comment: Great! It was a good case to spend time on ). See you around.